# Magento2 - How to add Tooltip text?

Tags: magento2, tooltip

I want to add tooltip text to My account and shopping cart link on header
See https://prnt.sc/r6r331

Answer (score 0):

Please try below,

Add in your template,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Show Tooltip!">On Hover</a>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/custom": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Add in **custom.js** file

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'popper',
    'domReady!'
], function($, Popper) {
    "use strict";
    window.Popper = Popper;

    $( function (){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        console.log('Tootip');
    });
});
```

> You also try below with less file:

```
<span class="my-tooltip">
    <a href="#" class="tooltip-toggle">On Hover?</a>
    <span class="tooltip-content">Test content</span>
</span>
```

And in less css

```
.my-tooltip {
    .lib-tooltip(right);
}
```

Above code not tested, but Hope this helps you!